# Passing strings in C-ADA binding application

Tags: c, ada

How can I pass strings from a C function to function in ADA (C-ADA binding)?

Any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you would create a subprogram on the Ada side that maps you C function:

```
procedure Foo (C : Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr);
pragma import (C, Foo, "foo");
```

so that from Ada you have access to `foo()`.

The custom is to then provide a more Ada friendly version, with:

```
procedure Foo (C : String) is
   S : Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr := New_String (C);
begin
   Foo (S);
   Free (S);      
end Foo;
```

If on the other hand the procedure is written in Ada and you want to call it from C, you would use:

```
procedure Foo (C : Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr);
pragma Export (C, Foo, "foo");
```

and from C you can then call:

```
extern void foo(char* c);
foo("bar");
```

Comment: More on this approach may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36101506/230513).

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't know about interfacing with Ada, so you have to do the interfacing work on the Ada side.  The package `Interfaces.C.Strings` contains operations for mapping C strings to Ada strings.