# Passing Strings from Ada function to C function

Tags: c, string, ada

Ada's strings are NOT null terminated like C's. I have a requirement in a C-Ada binding application where I need to pass a string that is allocated in Ada code to a C function. How will C recognize Ada strings in here as strings in C are usually simple char array terminated by a null char while this is not the case in Ada?

Any examples would be appreciated!

Comment: Check your manual: http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/aarm12_w_tc1/html/AA-B-3.html

Comment: Pass the ADA char-array along with its *length* to either `strncpy (newstr, ada_str, length);` and explicitly terminate `newstr` e.g. `newstr[length] = 0;` Or, if you have the ada string and the length and can use that same variable in the C code, just terminate the ada_string, e.g. `adastring[length] = 0;` (or if ada indexes from `1` instead of `0`, then `adastring[length+1] = 0;` (as long as the storage is available to add a nul-terminator)

Comment: Mostly a duplicate of your own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911763/passing-strings-in-c-ada-binding-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on @manuBriot's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35914904/230513) to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35914904/230513) on this topic, note that the convenient wrapper `procedure Foo` calls [`New_String`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-3-1.html) on the incoming Ada `String` to obtain a `chars_ptr`.

```
procedure Foo (C : String) is
   S : Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr := New_String (C);
begin
   …
end Foo;
```

Note also that `New_String` "is equivalent to `New_Char_Array(To_C(Str))`." When passed an Ada `String`, [`To_C`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-3.html) sets `Append_Nul` to `True` by default. As a result, Ada `Foo` calls C `foo` with a properly `null` terminated C string.

Comment: If I am allocating a string in ADA, how do I release memory after using that string in C side?

Comment: @AKay: Referring to the [code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35914904/230513) elided above, `Free(S)` will release the storage allocated for the `char_array` by `New_String`.